# Countif across multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, countif

I am trying to get a tally of how many times two values appear across multiple worksheets.

This formula does exactly what I need but only on **one** worksheet. When I expand the search range, I get a `#VALUE` error.

**This works:**

`=(COUNTIF('16-Feb'!A:J,A2)*AND(COUNTIF('16-Feb'!L:L,"email")))`

**This doesn't:**

`=(COUNTIF('9-Feb:26-Mar'!A:J,A2)*AND(COUNTIF('9-Feb:26-Mar'!L:L,"email")))`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `COUNTIF` values?

Comment: You can't use it like you're trying to. You have to add the separate `COUNTIF()`: `=(COUNTIF('16-Feb'!A:J,A2)*AND(COUNTIF('16-Feb'!L:L,"email")))+(COUNTIF('9-Feb'!A:J,A2)*AND(COUNTIF('9-Feb'!L:L,"email")))`

Comment: Basic research would tell you [CountIf does not support #D ranges](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-3-d-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-40ca91ff-9dcb-4ad1-99d2-787d0bc888b6)

Comment: Your formula is also highly suspect. What =(COUNTIF('16-Feb'!A:J,A2)*AND(COUNTIF('16-Feb'!L:L,"email")))` does is: if `email` appears *anywhere* in column `L`, count all whole cell instances of `A2` in columns `A:J`  otherwise return `0`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I want to count every time a name on a cover sheet (the name in A2) appears in a series of worksheets with the word, "email".  This formula does it.  =(COUNTIF('16-Feb'!A:J,A2)*AND(COUNTIF('16-Feb'!L:L,"email")))     but only on the tab labeled 16-Feb.  I need to expand it to all tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Do the COUNTIFs separately for each worksheet, then add them together:

```
=(COUNTIF('16-Feb'!A:J,A2)*AND(COUNTIF('16-Feb'!L:L,"email")))
+
(COUNTIF('9-Feb'!A:J,A2)*AND(COUNTIF('9-Feb'!L:L,"email")))
```

Comment: I'd rather not have to do all that since tabs (dates) will be continually added.  But I will try it.  Thx

Comment: OK  this works.  BUT since I'm dealing with potentially a years worth of data  it may not be practical =(COUNTIF('9-Feb'!A:J,A2)*AND(COUNTIF('9-Feb'!L:L,"email")))+(COUNTIF('12-Feb'!A:J,A2)*AND(COUNTIF('12-Feb'!L:L,"email")))